Reactive Mongo not saving CreatedBy user
I am using ReactiveMongoRepository to save my document.
I have used @EnableReactiveMongoAuditing annotation to audit my document.
When creating a new entity (document), only the date fields 'updateDate', and 'creationDate' are being set when 'creationUser' should also be set.
In my service I do the insertion to mongodb in the following way
@Override
public Mono<ResponseDTO> create(ReqDTO reqDTO) {

    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication().getName())
            .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error retrieving user from security context: {}", error.getMessage()))
            .flatMap(user -> {
                var toSave = mapper.mapToEntity(reqDTO);
                return repository.insert(toSave)
                        .map(savedEntity -> new ResponseDTO();
            });
}

I also have the configuration classes in case the service doesn't understand it.
@Component
public class UserAudtiting implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {

        String uname = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        return Optional.of(uname);
    }
}

My entity is the following:
@Document
@Getter
public class DocumentEntity {

@Id
@NonNull
private String id;

@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime creationDate;

@CreatedBy
private String creationUser;

@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime updateDate;

@LastModifiedBy
private String updateUser;

@Version
private Integer version;

Why is the creationUser not being saved?

Does this GitHub project help you ?
